# MongoDB get server

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, nosql

I try to connect to server and get database. It run properly but it VS2013 show me a warning :

> Warning   1   'MongoDB.Driver.MongoClientExtensions.GetServer(MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient)' is obsolete: 'Use the new API instead.

```
        string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
        var server = mongoClient.GetServer();
        var db = server.GetDatabase("bookstore");
        var bookCollection = db.GetCollection<Book>("Book");
```

Can someone help me solve this ? Tks for reading.

Answer (score 15):

The `MongoServer` class was deprecated in version 2.0.0 (see [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/releases)). You can call `GetDatabase()` directly on the `MongoClient` object:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
var db = mongoClient.GetDatabase("bookstore");
```

More documentation about connecting to the MongoDB server, retrieving a database, etc. can be found in the [reference documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/connecting/).

Comment: I tried it, but when i call Getdatabase() from Client. bookCollection.Save(book) didnt work. I tried to run bookCollection.InsertOneAsync(book); Nothing changed. Can u explained to me ? Tks for your help so much.

Comment: @Hana Sorry, would like to help out further, but don't have access to a Windows machine.

Comment: Using `mongoClient.GetDatabase` gives me an error that says `"MongoClient does not contain a definition for GetDatabase"`. So what is the alternative solution to get the database by its name?

Comment: @Rai According to the documentation it does. Check your version and if you can't get it to work, it's probably a good idea to ask a new question.

Comment: @Hana that method (`mongoClient.Getdatabase()`) returns an interface type (`IMongoDataBase`) not a concert type. and apparently that interface doesn't fit in `Save()`.

Comment: @Rai that is method not a property (`mongoClient.Getdatabase()`) and it returns an interface type (`IMongoDataBase`) not a concert type. so make sure you are receiving output from that method properly (however it is not much likely as per error you are mentioning).

Answer (score 1):

I changed my code to following:

```
var mongoUrl = new MongoUrl(connectionString);
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUrl);
MongoServer server = new MongoServer(MongoServerSettings.FromClientSettings(mongoClient.Settings));
```

Comment: How does this help?

Answer (score 0):

The example code from @Robby works, but it doesn't return what your code is expecting; it returns Interface objects. The C# driver was updated to utilize `Interface` methods, as well as a number of asynchronous functions, so updating your code is probably a good idea.

The new way to get a database is -- well, you don't get a database anymore. You get an `IMongoDatabase` which is an interface to the database. Also, you should not work with `MongoCollection`s anymore (from the `MongoDatabase` object), when you get an `IMongoDatabase` you will work with an `IMongoCollection`. Refactoring? You bet! But it's worth it.

I would also recommend putting your default database in the Mongo URL formatted connection strings. That way you can keep hard-coded constants, such as the database name, out of your code.

```
// Get your connection string -- use the URL format as in example below:
// name="MongoConnectionStr" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/bookstore"
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoConnectionStr"].ConnectionString;
var mongoUrl = MongoUrl.Create(connectionString);

var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

// Use the Mongo URL to avoid hard-coding the database name.
var db = new MongoClient(mongoUrl).GetDatabase(mongoUrl.DatabaseName);
// books below is an IMongoCollection
var books = db.GetCollection<Book>("Books");
```